# How to get greatest value of all integers in a 2d vector?

Tags: c++, iterator, 2d

I am trying to get maximum value my iterator is pointing at out of 2d array.

Example

Input

> Data = {{}, {3,11,4}, {1,2}, {5,6}};

Output

> max = 11

I have a 2d array and with `max_element` I tried to get the maximum out of the values in the array.

With a 1d iterator you can dereference the iterator and get the value i.e. `*iteratorOneD`. But how can I do something like this with a 2d iterator?

I tried a few things like this.

```
vector<vector <int>>::iterator position;
position = std::max_element(Data.begin(), Data.end());

int max = *position[0];

cout<< *position << endl;
```

But nothing worked yet. I receive this error.

> C2440 "Initialisierung": "std::vector<int,std::allocator>" cant be converted to an int

The output of `cout << *position << endl;`  is `std::vector(1062256, 1027080)`.
I would like to be able to assign one of these values to `int max`.

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) issue (`[]` precedes `*`). Try `int max = (*position)[0];`. But, for a proper answer, you'll need to provide a minimal, reproducible sample code.

Comment: Thanks it worked. You solved my problem.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. Do you want the greatest `vector` according to lexicographic order? Not the `vector` containing the greatest element?

Comment: I am not 100% sure I understand what you want to say but I want the greatest value of all integers in this 2d  vector `` vector < vector < int > >& Data ``  - but I think I did not transfered this through my post

Comment: Ok, that's not what you get from `position = std::max_element(Data.begin(), Data.end());` - you get an iterator to the greatest vector in lexicographical sort ordering.

Comment: But if I derefernce the iterator pointing to the highest value I actually get what I want (after that I only have to compare the values behind [0] and [1]:                                  
     "int max1, max2 = (*position)[0], (*position)[1];"

Comment: If so, it was pure coincidence. Look [here](https://godbolt.org/z/P1h86qz1h) - As you can see, it returns the `vector` containing `5` and `6`, not the `vector` containing `11`.

Comment: I think (as suggested in my earlier comment) you should add more details and clarity to your question, including extra code to make what you present reproducible.

Comment: @AdrianMole I added the clarification "_I want the greatest value of all integers in this 2d vector_" to the question. That should make it ok I think.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Meh - I think an `int main()` and a definition for `Data` would help.

Comment: @AdrianMole True - that'd make it even better. `Data` is a `vector<vector<int>>` though. The iterator says it is :)

Comment: ... and what is `cout << *position << endl;` supposed to do?

Comment: thanks to both of you. I will have another look and test your way @AdrianMole.

Comment: @AdrianMole Looks like OP is hoping for that to be an iterator to the greatest element in the inner vector - but gets compilation errors.

Comment: @tlau5 If you really want "_the greatest value of all integers in this 2d vector_",  you could try my suggestion (or a similar one if one pops up).

Comment: I think you are right. @Adrian Mole. I just wanted an elegant solution. I will try your way

Comment: @tlau5 Are you really replying to the right person?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an iterator "outside" `std::max_element` that keeps track of the greatest element so far.

```
int main() { 
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> Data{{}, {3,11,4}, {1,2}, {5,6}};

    // find the first non-empty vector
    auto ne = std::find_if(Data.begin(), Data.end(),
                           [](auto& v) { return !v.empty(); });

    if(ne == Data.end()) return 1; // no elements in **any** inner vector

    // set the inner iterator to the max element in the first non-empty vector
    auto inner = std::max_element(ne->begin(), ne->end());

    auto position = std::max_element(ne, Data.end(),
        [&inner](auto&, auto& v2) {
            if(v2.empty()) return false;

            // find the max_element in this inner vector
            auto tmp  = std::max_element(v2.begin(), v2.end());

            // is it greater than the one we had stored
            if(*inner < *tmp) {
                inner = tmp;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });

    std::cout << "the vector ";
    for(auto& col : *position) std::cout << col << ' ';
    std::cout << "contains the max element " << *inner << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
the vector 3 11 4 contains the max element 11
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort! Adrian Mole already told me some working solution but thanks anyway.

Comment: @tlau5 You're welcome! I see. Ok, the above gives you two iterators. One to the vector containing the `max_element` and one iterator to the actual element.

Answer (score 1):

From C++20, you can use range views to create a 1D view from your 2D vector

```
auto as1D = Data | std::views::join;
```

and then with range algorithms you can find the maximum element

```
int max = *std::ranges::max_element(as1D);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7zx19YTze)

Comment: Wow! Nice! I've said it before, but I really need to look closer at these range thingies.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Indeed, they're *really* convenient. It'll take some time for people to get used to how they work, e.g. `std::ranges::max_element(Data | std::views::join)` seems like an obvious transformation, but doesn't work. BTW, I read your answer, and copied the example `vector Data`, so thanks for that. I also added it to the question itself, so now everything is consistent as well :)